# jest enzyme reactJS - method executes regardless of return

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following method I want to test:

```
handleDayClick(e, day, {disabled}) {
        if (disabled) {
            // Do not update the state if the day is disabled
            return;
        }
        this.setState({ selectedDay: day });
        this.props.dateClick(day);
    };
```

So I wrote a mock function, passed it as a prop and figured I would test state and if the function gets called:

```
it('handleDayClick() should NOT set state.selectedDay, call props.dateClick when disabled', () => {
    let mockDateClick = jest.fn();
    const sidebar = shallow(<Sidebar dateClick={mockDateClick}/>);
    let e = 'whatever';
    let day = 'tomorrow';

    sidebar.instance().handleDayClick(e, day, true);
    expect(sidebar.state().selectedDay).toBe(undefined);
    expect(mockDateClick).toNotHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

The thing is that the state().selectedDay gets set to tomorrow. The value before calling the method is `2017-01-12T18:18:13.216Z`, so I am pretty sure the method does not exit on the render function.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your test, you are doing:  `sidebar.instance().handleDayClick(e, day, true);`

while handleDayClick is destructuring an object with the `disabled` key

```
handleDayClick(e, day, {disabled}) {
}
```

Try to call it like this : `sidebar.instance().handleDayClick(e, day, { disabled: true });`

In the future you might want to use tools like Flow to prevent errors https://flowtype.org/docs/react.html

you would have been able to detect it earlier by doing something like this :

```
handleDayClick(e: {}, day: string, {disabled}: boolean) {
}
```